# No such file or directory at - Perl dead file closes program

Tags: regex, perl

They want me to create a feed catalog, which is a table of all the jobs from
`autosys` and then all the infiles and outfiles that the jobs depend upon.

The idea is that, instead of calling my boss up at 3:00am when the job fails,
level one can match the failed job to a file, or vice versa, and hopefully
fix the issue.

The script takes in the `autosys` config file, takes out the `executable` line, substrings it,
opens up the file, and then regexes out a path line. It works fine except it gasses out
when it can't open up a file.

I am getting this error.

```
dead file handle No such file or directory at ./slurp_autosys_config.justexec2 line 10, <$autosys_fh> line 352.
```

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open my $autosys_fh, '<', "/data/autosys-us.cfg" or die "can't open file $!";

while ( my $cfg_line = <$autosys_fh> ) {

   if ($cfg_line =~ /executable/) {

      my $cut_cfg_line = substr "$cfg_line", 13;

      if ( $cut_cfg_line =~ /(\/\S*\.[sh,pl,ksh])/ ) {

         chomp($cut_cfg_line);
         open my $fh_cut_cfg, '<', $cut_cfg_line or die "dead file handle $!";

         while ( my $path = <$fh_cut_cfg> ) {
            if ( $path =~ /(\"\/\S*)\"/ ) {
               print "$cut_cfg_line --->  $path";
               sleep 1;
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

This is the results. It is what I want

```
walt@host:~/walt $ ./slurp_autosys_config.justexec2
/data/adp/UBSS/adploggerUBSS.sh.new --->  DIR="/data/scripts"
/data/evtUSBUCgediLoader.sh --->  $out="/data/px";
/data/evtUSBUCgediLoader.sh ---> $in="/data/infile";
/data/cboe_xml_hack_check.pl --->      my $xml="/data/C4symbolgroupdefconfig.xml";
/data/cboe_xml_hack_check.pl --->      my $xml="/data/qedefconfig.xml";
/data/WebDownloads/getCBOE_BC_csv.pl --->  my $reallysave   =    "/data/BCALLCLASSES.csv";
/data/WebDownloads/getCBOE_BC_csv.pl --->  my $save   =    "/data/CBOE_BC.csv";
/data/WebDownloads/getCBOE_BC_csv.pl --->  my $output_file="/data/CBOE_BC.csv";
/data/WebDownloads/getCBOE_BC_csv.pl --->  system("/data/CBOE_BC_Checker.pl");
/data/dbscripts/getCBOE_BC.pl --->      my $bc_file = "/data/CBOE_BC.csv";
/data/dbscripts/getCBOE_BC.pl --->      my $bc_file = "/data/C2_BC.csv";
/data/dbscripts/getCBOE_BC.pl --->      my $bc_file = "/data/CBOE_BC.csv";
/data/dbscripts/getCBOE_BC.pl --->      my $bc_file = "/data/C2_BC.csv";
/data/WebDownloads/CBOE_restricted.pl --->  $compliance_dir="/data/compliance";
/data/WebDownloads/CBOE_restricted.pl --->  $puc_file="/data/Restricted.csv";
/data/WebDownloads/CBOE_restricted.pl --->  $final_file="/data/Restricted.csv";
/data/WebDownloads/CBOE_restricted.pl --->  #$second_file="/data/ISERestricted.csv";
/data/checkClosingPrices.pl --->  $pxdir="/db/irdb/px";

dead file handle No such file or directory at ./slurp_autosys_config.justexec2 line 10, <$autosys_fh> line 352.
```

When I check for this file - file 352 - I can't open up the file. There is nothing in it.

- How do I make the program run if there is an empty file?
- How do I keep track of the empty files?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open my $autosys_fh, '<', "/data/autosys-us.cfg" or die "can't open file $!";

while (my $cfg_line = <$autosys_fh>) {
   if ($cfg_line =~ /executable/) {
      print "$. $cfg_line";
   }
}
```

This is the troubleshoot results - it is a dead file.

```
 walt@host:~/walt $ ./cont-executable | head -22 | tail -2
 352 executable = /data/checkClosingPrices.v2.pl
 365 executable = /data/cboe_quote_rate_check.sh
 walt@host:~/walt $
 walt@host:~/walt $ cat  /data/checkClosingPrices.v2.pl
 cat: /data/checkClosingPrices.v2.pl: No such file or directory
 walt@host:~/walt $i
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `next` to skip the line, instead of dying?

Comment: > How do i make the program run if there is an empty file?
One suggestion is that you don't *`die`* over it. `open my $fh_cut_cfg, '<', $cut_cfg_line or die "dead file handle $!";`

Comment: I don't see how an empty line could cause this problem. If the line is empty, it won't match `/executable/`

Comment: You can open empty files; I think you mean non-existent files (I'm also assuming that's what you mean by "dead file").

Comment: Also, your regex `/(\/\S*\.[sh,pl,ksh])/` is not doing what you think it is. `[sh,pl,ksh]` will match a *single* `h`, `k`, `l`, `p`, `s`, or `,`. `(?:sh|pl|ksh)` will match either `sh`, `pl`, or `ksh`.

Comment: @capser: Are you saying that `/data/checkClosingPrices.v2.pl` doesn't exist? Or that it's empty?

Comment: @capser: There is no such thing as a "dead file" so no one knows what you mean. The error message says `No such file or directory` so the file doesn't exist. That is why you're getting an error when you try to open it. If you didn't write `or die "dead file handle $!"` then your program wouldn't die! It's best if you issue a warnings and continue to the next file. See my solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you. It fixes an error in your first regex ( `[sh,pl,ksh]` matches only a *single* character and is the same as `[,hklps]` ) and warns and continues if any of the files can't be opened.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $autosys_fh, '<', '/data/autosys-us.cfg' or die "Can't open autosys config file: $!";

while ( <$autosys_fh> ) {

   next unless /executable/;

   chomp;
   my $cut = substr $_, 13;
   next unless $cut =~ m{ / \S* \. (?: sh | pl | ksh ) }x;

   open my $cut_fh, '<', $cut or do {
      warn qq{Can't open file "$cut": $!};
      next;
   };

   while ( <$cut_fh> ) {
      next unless m{ "/ \S* " }x;
      my $path = $_;
      print "$cut ---> $path";
      sleep 1;
   }
}
```